# ngFor loop over array returning only n items

Tags: angular, ngfor

Let's say I have the following array in Angular 10: `[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]` and I want to use `ngFor` to only display 5 items at a time going one step at a time sliding.

I have the following piece of code:

```
<categories class="col-2" *ngFor= "let category of categories | slice:index:index+5;" [category]="category"></categories>
```

My main problem is that we I get to the end of the array, instead of 5 elements only 4 or less are being returned as a result that I am reaching the end of my array.

My desired output is for example when I get index 9 to have returned the items of: `[8,9,0,1,2]`.

Or when I get index -1 to get: `[9,0,1,2,3]`.

How could I avoid this and connect the end to the beginning?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the built in slice pipe in the template. Declare the value to hold the limit in your ts file or you can specify directly in the template.

[CheckThis Ex](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ngfor-async-dygi5y)

```
 <ul>
  <li *ngFor="let option of options | slice:0:limit">{{option}}</li>
</u>
```

And in the ts file specify the limit

public limit =4;

If the limit is 4 then it will show only 4 items.

Comment: Hi! I have edited my question to clarify further my desired output as unfortunately your answer didn't solve my issue. However, many thanks for Helping! :D